# Non-inverting NE5532 with 1.56 gain not working

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, preamp, non-inverting, ne5532

I made 4 preamp's for laptops and cellphones using 2 NE5532 IC's. The expected gain is 1.56 so, I used a 5.6K resistor as the feedback one and a 10K from the inverting input to a 47uF bipolar capacitor which goes to ground. I fed the output of the NE5532 to a LM1876 with a gain of 21. The 4 preamps aren't working properly as they are atenuating the signal instead of amplifing it. Also, the 5.6k resistor is being measured as about 3k when plugged in the circuit. Any ideai on what could be wrong?
All of the op-amps are supplied with +-20V with 2 capacitor, 10uF and 100nF near to each of the +Vcc and -Vee pins.

[image]

Comment: You can't measure the value of a resistor when it's fitted to a circuit like this.

Comment: What's your input source impedance?

Comment: I know it wouldn't be an acurate measuring. I measured with the circuit suply reails disconnected, and, the 3 of the NE5532 op-amps read 5.6K while one of them measured about 3k.

Comment: I don't know what's the source inpedance, I used a Dell laptop's headphone output as a source. But I'm pretty sure it's way less than 47K as it wokred good when I fed this source straight to the LM1876 circuit.

Comment: @GabrielSantos try using a larger resistor and see what happens (~100kohm).

Comment: @ErnestoG as the input impedance? R1?

Comment: Check that the supply rails are present right at the op-amp pins, and measure the value of R1. Also make sure C2,3,7 are 10uF and not 10nF.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit simulates fine in LTspice. I didn't have a model for the 5532 so I used an LT1028A. I get 3.86dB (x1.56) gain midband, low frequency is down 3dB at 1.7 Hz and flat out to over 300 kHz.

I would go over your build again and make sure everything is connected correctly and the resistor and capacitor values are correct. Measure the DC offset at the output of the opamp (not after the cap) and see that it's close to 0 V with no input.
If your source was driving the LM1876 circuit okay it should drive the NE5532 okay, as the input impedances are about the same.

One thing you could try, although I don't think it will make much difference is remove C6 and connect R3 right to ground.

Is this built on a breadboard? If so you may be getting poor connections or high frequency oscillation, do you have a scope to test for that?

Comment: No, it's already soldered. I tested it on a breadbord before and it worked fine with a 130mVRMS 60hZ sine wave

Comment: @GabrielSantos If it worked fine on a breadboard, then chances are that the circuit itself is fine and you just made a mistake soldering it together.

Answer (score 0):

Power rails and decoupling would be my initial thoughts, note in particular that the 5532 is not remotely happy at less then about 10V total supply (They give it as +-5V in the datasheet, which catches some people out).

Have you had a poke with a scope to see if it is taking off at a few hundred kHz to a few MHz? There is plenty of gain (and GBP) there that a poorly considered common ground or missing decoupling could very easily make it honk up above the audio band, and this can show up as (among other things) lower then expected gain.

Does the opamp work in isolation (lift one end of C2 or C3 and probe there)?